# Apache Nifi: singleton instance python process - ExecuteStreamCommand or similar

Tags: apache-nifi

New to Apache NiFi. Would like to know if possible to implement the scenario:

- there is a Python script which is capable of reading the file from `stdin` and putting the conversion result to `stdout`
- the script cannot be defined in ExecuteScript, as NumPy is a dependency
- the script initialization is pretty time-consuming
- the script loads several GB of data dictionaries into memory, that are required to do the conversion

Is there a way to host a singleton instance of such script within a NiFi processor? The life of the instance should last until the processor is stopped.

The goal is to avoid costly script initialization per flow file and associated memory re-allocations.

Associated question: does NiFi allow to buffer flow files and pass a collection to a processor as a whole?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can't do with ExecuteStreamCommand the `singleton instance`

however some ideas:

`singleton instance` - rework your python script to receive/reply flowfiles through http, start it once and that's like what you want except start-stop requirement

`buffer flow files and pass a collection` :

- use mergecontent with tar format to put several flow files in one tarball archive,
- then process all files in tar with your python script and return new tarball with processed files
- then extract tar archive in nifi

Comment: yep, script-as-a-service is also a considered option. thank you